# git rebase local branch to remote master

Tags: git, github, command, rebase, git-bash

I am totally new to git and in an emergency to use git commands to rebase my local branch to remote master.
Things happened like this.

1.I forked a repo [Logan676/seadroid](https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid) from [haiwen/seadroid](https://github.com/haiwen/seadroid) on Github

2.I created a new branch called `lguo` on `Logan676/seadroid`

3.Then do some changes, commits. At the same time the origin master `haiwen/seadroid` also updated by others.

4.Now I want to rebase `lguo` to the latest origin master of `haiwen/seadroid`.

I used commands below:

```
git fetch origin            # Updates origin/master
git rebase origin/master    # Rebases current branch onto origin/master
```

And the output in gitbash is: `Current branch lguo is up to date`.

But team members told me that my branch was rebased to the forked repo master not the origin master.
I am so confused about that, did I miss any command?

BTW, I notice someone wrote like this

```
git clone
git checkout -b dev_branch
[do some changes, commit]
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push origin HEAD:master
```

so should I add the last command line

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

I am afraid to use that command, I worried that will damage the origin master? what should I do?
Any help from you will be appreciated.

Comment: does you lguo branch include new commits not present in master?

Comment: yes, I added ten new commits which were not present in master. And in the same way, the master has a lot of commits which were not present in my lguo branch either.

Comment: In the meantime, I suggest you do ```git push origin lguo``` to have your branch in github too. This won't harm master in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote *origin* points to your clone *Logan676/seadroid* on github, not to *haiwen/seadroid*. Your local clone of *Logan676/seadroid* is not aware of the original *haiwen/seadroid* repository.

You need to add the original repository as an additional remote to your local clone:

```
git remote add haiwen git@github.com:haiwen/seadroid.git
```

Then you can do

```
git fetch haiwen
git rebase haiwen/master
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to push from local branch A to remote branch B, in this case both branches have diverged and the push will be rejected. You can still force push, but it would mean losing whatever commits happened in master since you created branch lguo.

I reccomend you do the following

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge lguo
```

This will probably need some merging.  The resulting master branch has all the changes you did on lguo. Finally:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I wonder the difference between `git fetch origin` with `git checkout master git pull origin master`. I already used the fetch command to update, so do I need to checkout master and pull origin master again?

Comment: ```Git fetch``` updates your references with the remote, but leaves your working copy untouched. ```Git pull``` does both the update and applies them over your working copy. Doing a pull roughly equals to doing git fetch followed by git merge. If you already did a fetch, doing pull means doing git fetch again and then doing git merge.

Comment: As I am a beginner of git, I really confused how to use the command step by step.Should I command like this： (now I am on lguo branch) 1. `git checkout master` 2.`git pull origin master` 3. `git merge lguo` 4. `git push origin master`. it turned out to be wrong. the local project has errors in eclipse due to conflict issues so I quit  on step 3.

Comment: And when I use `git pull origin master`, the output in gitbash is `From https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid` which is not correct. That is not the origin remote url. the right url should be `https://github/haiwen/seadroid`, So that is what I am asking, how to change the url because I want to fetch latest updates from the origin master.

Comment: I told you would probably have to do some merging. Depending on the changes between the branches, it's for you to decide which changes should take precedence.  Git cannot just guess. What os are you using? There are graphical merge tools to help you pick from either branch. Now, regarding your remote issue, you said you forked a repo, and created a new branch on Logan/seadroid. This means your working copy is a clone from your fork, not from the original haiwen/seadroid. Don't let the name origin mislead you. After all, if you were working directly with haiwen, you wouldn't be able to push.

Comment: I have been using Windows 8 as OS, and use git command to manage code. I fixed the issue, it because the remote url is `Logan676/seadroid` not `haiwen/seadroid`. So I removed `Logan676/seadroid` and added `haiwen/seadroid` as origin remote url.

Comment: You won't be able to push to haiwen, unless its owner ads you to the developers group